# Amazon MWS with PHP integration

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, integrate

I am new to amazon mws. I want to do the mws api integration with php. I have all the credentials whatever needed like secret key, seller id, and etc.

Basically i want to display all my orders in my php website. I tried with use of developer guide which is provided by the mws documentation. but i could not get a proper idea of how to integrate api in my php site.

Comment: Please provide code sample what you have tried to implement so far and specify your problem more.

Comment: Hi did you managed to do something? I tried few times to do similar think but without working example it is very hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First steps in creating an MWS client:

1. Create a professional seller account on Amazon (fees will apply)
2. Get credentials for that account
3. Download the [PHP client library](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/php.html)
4. Add your credentials from step 2 to the PHP code
5. Start developing

In your case you'll want to look at the Reports API, specifically at `RequestReport` to request a list of orders, which you'll then fetch through `GetReport`. Eventually you'll probably need to call `ManageReportSchedule` to automatically create reports ready to fetch.

Comment: Hazzit, Thanks a lot for the solution.  One more query: which framework/platform is the best for this kind of application? PHP/Python...? can i fetch all the things from amazon seller account to my website like list of orders, product inventory, keywords tracker, product list, total sales and etc?

Comment: You could pretty much use any platform you wish. I would suggest though to use one where there is a client library available, which currently would be C#, PHP and Java. While it is totally possible to write your own library (I've done that), some things are hard to get right, specifically getting the signature to work. BTW, I linked the Products client library, here's the Orders libary: https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/orders/orders/v20130901/php.html

Answer (score 2):

### Verify Credentials & Play Around With API:

Please verify if your credentials are correct & you do have orders in your seller account to download from. You can use amazon's scratchpad here: [Amazon MWS scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.in/scratchpad/index.html)

 On scratchpad you want to use following methods.

 API Selection: **Orders**

 Operation: **ListOrders**

 You can also refer to this [API Guide](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_ListOrders.html) to better understand scratchpad.

---

### Integration:

Download PHP library from [Amazon MWS](https://developer.amazonservices.co.uk/gp/mws/api.html?ie=UTF8&group=orders&section=orders&version=latest)

1. You want to add your  MWS credentials in this file `MarketplaceWebServiceOrders/Samples/.config.inc.php`
2. Here you put in values that you used to play around at scratchpad 

   `MarketplaceWebServiceOrders/Samples/ListOrders.php`

   eg: CreatedAfter, LastUpdatedAfter, OrderStatus
3. Run this file in browser & you will receive data in XML format `MarketplaceWebServiceOrders/Samples/ListOrders.php`